# Firebase onCall Cloud Function Request Returning "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Getting error when trying to access my cloud function:

> {"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
>
> If the client trigger is invoked, but the request is in the wrong
> format, such as not being JSON, having invalid fields, or missing the
> data field, the request is rejected with 400 Bad Request, with an
> error code of INVALID_ARGUMENT.

Firebase Documentation: [Firebase Error Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference)

**index.js** in functions directory

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./fir-email-b4c1f-firebase-adminsdk-xj7ug-d01651ffc9");


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://fir-email-b4c1f.firebaseio.com"
});



    exports.getUserByEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

const email = data.email;

return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
    .then(userRecord => {
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
    const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
    return { userData: userData };
})
```

});

**authentication.js** calling function in project main directory

```
    function retrieveUserData() {

    var emailString = "test@gmail.com";
    var userEmail = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getUserByEmail');

    userEmail({email: emailString}).then(function(result) {
        // Read result of the Cloud Function.
        var emailResult = result.data.text;
        console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', emailResult.toJSON());


    })

}
```

Not fully understanding the error. I assume I am missing an argument based on the documentation. Can someone guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems you are indeed missing an argument. Your first parameter (`data`) for the `getUserByEmail()` function is supposed to be an object that contains the property: `email` from this line: `const from = data.sender;`. But when calling it you pass in an object with only a `text` property. Which means, when your cloud function runs, data.email is undefined.

Probably, you mean to call the function like this:

```js
userEmail({email: emailString}).then(function(result) {
        // Read result of the Cloud Function.
}
```

UPDATE: On the second issue:
Your cloud function returns an object with just a lone property: `userData`, so if you want to log the returned value in your output, you'll need to replace

```js
var emailResult = result.data.text;
console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', emailResult.toJSON());
```

with this:

```js
var emailResult = result.data.userData;
console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', emailResult);
```

All the extra fields: `result.data.text` do not exist on the object returned. And you already converted your firebase response to JSON in your cloud function. You can't be doing that again on the client

Comment: Can you please look at the updated code. I am now getting a "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined"

Comment: If the userRecord is undefined, you should confirm that the user email you provided actually exists in the database

Comment: the user email is confirmed in the database

Comment: In the database? As in a collection?

Comment: In authentication under users.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting wrong. I've edited my answer. Apply those changes and let me know how it goes

Comment: "Successfully fetched user data: undefined" The function now works successfully but for some reason it is still undefined.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant `result.data.userData`. Editing my answer. Check if that works

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are very much apreciated.